# Can't call a function from another script because of a var is local

Tags: php, function, scope

I got a problem that is same as the subject, here is the codes.

Script A:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mysql');
```

The above works fine so I exclude the `die()` clause here for everyone easiler to read.

Script B:

```
function get_news(){
/* a select query */
$result = mysqli_query($con, $news_sql)
or die(mysqli_error($con);
/* other codes follow */
};
```

Script C:

```
require_once "Script B";
get_news();
```

The above fail and after some testings, I confirmed that the problem lies on the var `$con` in Script B.

There are at least 2 ways to solve this:

a) replace `$con` with `mysqli_connect();`
b) define `$con` again within the function in Script B

Although this solve my problem but seems that both are not good practice. Should I define the `$con` as a `$_global var`? Would you please suggest other better approach.

Thanks a lot!

Original code of Script B:

```
function get_news(){
    $news_sql = "SELECT * from pink_news ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 3";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $news_sql)
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<div class='news'><ul><li>";
    echo "<img src='" . $rows['img'] . "'>";
    echo "<h2>" . $rows['headline'] . "</h2>";
    echo "<p>" . $rows['content'] . "</p>";
    echo "</li></ul></div>";
    };
};
```

Comment: assign it as global variable global $con; or include the script a in your page and pass the parameter to the function get_new($con);

Comment: Thank you very much jothi, this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include `script A` to you page

```
include 'connection.php';
```

Then pass `$con` to your function as

```
get_news($con);// pass connection to your function
```

And in script B use it as

```
function get_news($con){
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `require_once "Script A"` to script B.. that should solve the problem

Comment: Thank you Manish, have a nice day :)